# Unable to convert classes into dex format Unity

Tags: google-play, admob, unity-game-engine

Using the google play games services and Admob plugin I cannot seem to get my back to build into an APK and I am receiving the following error message. Any help would be appreciated as I have removed some duplicate files but I am still failing to find why I cannot build my app.

I am using Unity Unity 5.6.1f1 (64-bit).

game services: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity Ads: https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Jack/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

    stderr[
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbyb;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbyc;
    2 errors; aborting
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Some Background**

When Unity builds your project for Android, it invokes several tools from the Android SDK. As part of that process, it converts all of your native (Java) code for Android into a file format called DEX (Dalvik executable).

All of your Android plugins get built up into a single package using that tool. The problems start when a few plugins have the same compiled Java code (classes) in them. This will cause the DEX tool to fail with an error like the one you're seeing:

> Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbyb;
>       Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbyc;

This means that classes with those names were already included in another library, and so they cannot be added again.

**Possible Causes**

As explained above, this error occurs when you have duplicate plugins in your project; this can happen in different scenarios, here are some examples:

- The same plugin is included more than once, under different folders of the project.
- The same plugin is included more than once with different versions.
- A plugin contains other dependencies "embedded" inside it, but these dependencies are already included in the project in some form.

**How To Fix**

You should look up duplicate Android plugins in your project and eliminate them (keep only 1 copy). From the error message you posted, the issue here is related to Google play services libraries. You should look into that (libraries named play-services-xxxx.aar).

**Paid Help (Shameless Plug)**

I provide a professional service for fixing this exact kind of issue. In case you (or anyone else) are not able to resolve such an issue themselves, feel free to [contact me](http://linktrack.info/.1zrtx) and get it solved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have looked at all my plugins starting with play-services and cannot see any duplicate files. I have put a link to a screenshot of my list of play-services files. Thanks.

Comment: You have mixed versions of google play services. All libraries should have the same version.

Comment: Can you advise on this as I have installed the two plugins I need, not sure how to progress. Thanks.

Comment: Yes from my experience it causes problems. Exactly like the one you're seeing.

Comment: I have removed the old plugin files and built my apk but now the application crashed. I know you provide a service to fix build errors but could I use your service to advice me on how to get google play services and admob to work together in unity?

Comment: Sure. Please contact me in private

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem after add admob in my project, here are 2 possible solutions:

1. Go to the file >> build settings and change the option internal to gradle
2. Open libs folders separately of both Facebook SDK and Google Play services and delete the matching files

It would be something like (support v4)